# Некорректно работает закрытие формы с async task

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

При попытке закрыть форму с работающим async task, выскакивает ошибка для new Form 1. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Адресат вызова создал исключение."

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
                
        private void AddWindow_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 ukl = new Form2 ();
            ukl.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(AddWindow_FormClosed);
            ukl.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Форма 2

```
 static CancellationTokenSource cts;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await DoSomeThing(cts.Token);
        }

        async Task DoSomeThing(CancellationToken token)
        {

            while(double.Parse(label1.Text )< 100)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                label1.Text = (double.Parse(label1.Text) + 1).ToString();
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        }

        private async void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.Cancel();
            await DoSomeThing(cts.Token);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Остановка не моментальная, отклик на токен можно улучшить. При обращении к `label` после того как форма уничтожена может произойти что угодно. Поэтому прерывать работу с UI нужно моментально.

```
async Task DoSomeThing(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while(double.Parse(label1.Text )< 100)
        {
            label1.Text = (double.Parse(label1.Text) + 1).ToString();
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}
```

В Closed вообще какая-то бессмыслица. Предположу, что нужно что-то такое.

```
private Task task;
private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts;

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    task = DoSomeThing(cts.Token);
}

private async void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        await task;
        cts.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Ну и я бы этот код отмены из Closed в Closing перенес

Comment: Спасибо большое! подскажите, с точки зрения синтаксиса, FormClosing не нужен, если и без него предложенное Вами решение работает?

Comment: @Dodge_this возможно, но есть риск, что выскочит исключение, если форма задиспозится до того как метод `DoSomeThing` будет остановлен. Кстати, дополнил немного код.

Comment: @Dodge_this нашел еще один косяк, cts не должен быть `static`, исправил код.